# Смена осей координат

Tags: c#, матрицы, вектор

у меня есть матрица 4х4 из движка RenderWare.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне хочется переделать её в формат Collada, как можно это сделать?
У меня есть черновой код, но местами вращение неверное.

```
    public static Matrix4x4 Transform(Matrix4x4 solidTransform)
    {
        var position = new Vector3(solidTransform.M41, solidTransform.M42, solidTransform.M43);
        var newPosition = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y, position.Z);

        var rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromRotationMatrix(solidTransform);

        float x = rotation.X;
        float y = rotation.Y;
        float z = rotation.Z;
        float w = rotation.W;

        float[,] identityMatrix = {
             { 1, 0, 0},
             { 0, 1, 0},
             { 0, 0, 1},
         };

        float[,] matrix4x4 = {
             { 0, 0, 0 },
             { 0, 0, 0 },
             { 0, 0, 0 },
         };

        float[,] symetricalMatrix = {
             { (-(y * y) - (z * z)), x* y, x*z},
             { x* y, (-(x * x) - (z * z)), y*z},
             { x* z, y*z, (-(x * x) - (y * y))}
         };

        float[,] antiSymetricalMatrix = {
             { 0, -z, y},
             { z, 0, -x},
             { -y, x, 0}
         };

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                matrix4x4[i, j] = identityMatrix[i, j]
                    + (2 * symetricalMatrix[i, j])
                    + (2 * w * antiSymetricalMatrix[i, j]);
            }
        }

        Matrix4x4 final = solidTransform;

        final.M11 = matrix4x4[0, 0];
        final.M12 = matrix4x4[0, 1];
        final.M13 = matrix4x4[0, 2];

        final.M21 = matrix4x4[1, 0];
        final.M22 = matrix4x4[1, 1];
        final.M23 = matrix4x4[1, 2];

        final.M31 = matrix4x4[2, 0];
        final.M32 = matrix4x4[2, 1];
        final.M33 = matrix4x4[2, 2];

        // position
        final.M41 = newPosition.X;
        final.M42 = newPosition.Y;
        final.M43 = newPosition.Z;

        return final;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цель сделать конверт карты из игры NFS Underground в блендер, данная формула поможет это сделать для всех частей игр.

Comment: Вы мудрите. Одна единственная матрица преобразования 4x4 пишется руками, так чтобы в каждой колонке и строке был единственный ненулевой элемент: `1` или `-1`, причем в правом-нижнем углу всегда `1`. На нее умножаются все входные матрицы. Ее чуть ли не перебором можно угадать.

Comment: мне главное чтобы заработало) в итоге как надо сделать, если с примером кода?

Answer (score 0):

Вы перемудрили. Это решается умножением на одну матрицу 4х4, которая пишется на глазок.

Пусть `X1`, `Y1`, `Z1` - исходные направления осей, а `X2`, `Y2`, `Z2` - желаемые направления. Путем внимательного рассматривания ваших картинок, выражаете первые через вторые:

- `X1 = X2` (вправо)
- `Y1 = Z2` (вверх)
- `Z1 = -Y2` (на себя)

Теперь подставляем `X2=[1,0,0]`, `Y2=[0,1,0]`, `Z2=[0,0,1]`. Получаем:

- `X1 = [1,0,0]`
- `Y1 = [0,0,1]`
- `Z1 = [0,-1,0]`

Теперь пишем те же самые числа не в строчку, а в столбик (X1, Y1, Z1):

```
X1= Y1= Z1=
 1   0   0
 0   0  -1
 0   1   0
```

Дополняем до размера 4х4 добавлением нулей справа и снизу, и единички в правом-нижнем углу:

```
 1   0   0   0
 0   0  -1   0
 0   1   0   0
 0   0   0   1
```

Теперь умножаем входные матрицы на эту (слева эта матрица, справа входная).

Comment: Простите, у меня очень плохо с матаном, как это все представить в виде финального кода? Большое спасибо за ваш ответ, очень хотелось бы проверить работоспособность, много времени уже потратил на все это)

Comment: @Kenix Фиг вам а не код. Вам остается перемножить две матрицы, а это не уровень "плохо с матаном", а уровень "мне впадлу гуглить". Да и с C# я не знаком...

Comment: Я умножил, сцена полностью в неправильном пространстве, либо я что-то не так делаю
    Matrix4x4 final = solidTransform;

            Matrix4x4 mulMat = new Matrix4x4(
                 1,   0,   0,   0,
                 0,   0, - 1,   0,
                 0,   1,   0,   0,
                 0,   0,   0,   1
            );

           return mulMat * final;
https://i.gyazo.com/ffbb7e1cf5e9f1c242ede16922bb9eb0.jpg

Comment: приложил скриншот

Comment: @Kenix А если вообще ничего не преобразовывать, как это выглядит? Как на скрине в вопросе?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/8c5c83f7b8ada8b03ee2dd298ec5b3f9.jpg
вот так

Comment: @Kenix Дык оно вроде уже правильно выглядит? Разные направления осей координат влияют только на поворт, а у вас уже все нормально повернуто?

Comment: Проблема с вращением объектов, вот к примеру, другие части локации в дали вообще из-за неправильного угла поворота
https://i.gyazo.com/fc080ea811beee5def4455bd60219db8.jpg

Comment: Вот к примеру дальний объект, если изменить вращение на 0, он хорошо встанет (просто пример)
https://imgur.com/a/RbUmdio

Comment: @Kenix Мне кажется дело не в осях. Если бы было в них, у вас бы вообще все было повернуто, а тут только отдельные модельки.

Comment: Те объекты, что стоят ровно имеют 0 0 0 (по ейлеру), это касается и дорог и прочего, остальные объекты у которых задано вращение уже неправильно повернуты.

Comment: @Kenix Как в файлах хранятся повороты, как матрицы или как углы эйлера? Если углы, попробуйте попереставлять их местами и поменять знаки. Если матрицы, попробуйте транспонировать (только верхнюю-левую 3х3 часть, конечно).

Comment: Оказалось как вы предполагали до этого, но даже круче. Я выставил большинству объектов 0 0 0 вращение + 0 0 0 позицию (через создание новой матрицы) и 80% карты выглядит круто, но есть небольшая часть объектов, в которых нужно задать позицию и там есть некий оффсет похоже.